# InfoPath 2013 - Text field (multi-line) does not word break when displayed in Email

Tags: infopath

On opening a submitted InfoPath 2013 form via its SharePoint Form Library, a form displays as designed (correct formatting etc), whether fully or partially populated. However, when viewed via email (Outlook 2010)*, the formatting is broken because populated multi-line text field's do not word break and therefore stretch horizontally across the page, placing all text on a single line and therefore breaking any width set in the form design itself. Multi-line is set in the display properties for these fields.
 Is there a way to ensure multi-line text fields word break when sent and displayed via email? Rich-text fields are not an option as an alternative I'm afraid.

*The form is sent as an email via Data Connection settings.

Comment: it looks more like Outlook issue rather than infopath. Do  you experience same behaviour on the Outlook 2013?

Comment: Thanks for responding Marek. Unfortunately, the same issue is replicated with Outlook 2013 also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by doing the following -

- Uncheck 'Multi-line' for all text fields in the form view that is to be sent via email.('Multi-line' is an option in the Display tab of each Text Box property's).

I now have 3 views -

Default view - Text fields have multi-line checked.

Email view - Text fields don't have multi-line checked.

Read-only view (this is the view for users opening the form direct from the form library) - All text fields have multi-line checked.

This serves the purpose of correctly displaying populated Multi-Lines of text in a form, in both email and via the form library itself.

Comment: This, however, would eliminate all carriage returns that the user has inputted. Use with caution.